# How to solve for different input for dir command in MatLab?

Tags: regex, image, matlab, dir

I am reading the images from a folder by using the below code in MatLab

```
[folder1] = uigetdir();
f=dir(folder1);

for k=1:size(f,1)-2
    new_file=f(k+2).name;
end
[idx,idx]=sort(cellfun(@(x) str2num(char(regexp(x,'\d*','match'))),new_file));
filename1=new_file(idx);
```

This code works for images in the folder with name "test_base1", "test_base2", ....

I am facing an error with a different input for this expression.

```
For file = {'test_30min1','test_30min10','test_30min2'};
```

it gives error as follows

```
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
```

I tried giving `regexp(x,'\w*','match')` and many other combinations in this expression. I am not able to get the solution. May i know what is the solution for this??

Comment: The error specifically refers to `cellfun`, not `regexp`, and even tells you how you how you might fix it: "Set 'UniformOutput' to false."  Check out the help for `cellfun` ... `cellfun(...,'UniformOutput',false);`.

Comment: Hey how come it is working when the input file={test_1min} but not working for file={test_1min1}.. both inputs are of same type. Only the elements inside the input change but not the type of file

Comment: `str2num(char(regexp('test_1min','\d*','match')))` only match one digit: 1. `str2num(char(regexp('test_1min1','\d*','match')))` matches two: both of the 1's. If you only want to match digits at the end of the file name, then use this regexp pattern instead: `'\d*$'`.

Comment: So there is no option to match two numbers in regexp?? "Set 'UniformOutput' to false is the only solution???